# Discord PY: Interaction Failed, Confirmation to kick

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to create a command wherein the user will be able to kick a member while the bot will ask the user to confirm whether to kick or not. When I tested the code, I dont get any errors in the terminal although I do get one on Discord saying "Interaction Failed." How may I fix this issue?Is there also a way for me to add a function wherein if the cancelled button is pressed? Saying "Cancelled kick." Im also quite new to dpy

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    username_1 = ctx.message.author.name
    avatar_1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Kick {member}?**", color= 0x303136)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed, components = [
        [Button(label="Confirm", style="3", emoji = "✅", custom_id="button1"), Button(label="Cancel", style="4", emoji = "❌", custom_id="button2")]
        ])
    username_1 = ctx.message.author.name
    avatar_1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
    conf=discord.Embed(title=f'{member} has been kick', color= 0x303136)
    conf.set_author(name=f"kicked by {username_1}", icon_url=avatar_1)
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await interaction.send(content = conf, ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to the interaction for the discord to confirm that everything went well.
Try:

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(content = conf, ephemeral=True)
```

This way you will be responding to an interaction by sending a message.
About your second question, please specify which fork of `discord.py` you are using.